# Storing a matrix table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, matrix

I'm currently working on a recommendation engine which uses a item-based collaborative filter to recommend restaurants to the user. I want to calculate a similarity between restaurants using an adjusted cosine similarity, which all works fine.

Now I want to store these similarities in the database so I can just retrieve the similarity between subjects from there so I can predict a rating for a subject the user hasn't reviewed yet.
A matrix could look like this: (Where R1 is restaurant 1, R2 is restaurant 2, etc.)

```
   |  R1  |  R2  |  R3  |  R4  |
R1 |  1   | 0.75 | 0.64 | 0.23 |
R2 | 0.75 |  1   | 0.45 | 0.98 |
R3 | 0.64 | 0.45 |  1   | 0.36 |
R4 | 0.23 | 0.98 | 0.36 |  1   |
```

This is a very small version of a matrix, since the amount of restaurants could exceed 20k rows in my database.

What would be the easiest/best way to store this in my database using entity framework? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there just one matrix in table or multiple

Comment: It is just this matrix, will be quite huge when the app is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table with following columns

1. MatrixValueId
2. MatrixId
3. FirstIndex string, contains values like 'R1','R2' ...
4. SecondIndex string, contains values like 'R1','R2' ...
5. Value float, contains values like 1.00, 0.23

Matrix in your example stored within 16 record with same MatrixId

Comment: If I would have around 20k restaurants, won't that mean that I'll have an explosion of rows?

Comment: It's ok for 20k restaurants in this way for storing and calculating values

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Why do you have the matrixvalueid though?

Comment: MatrixValueId is required column, it's record id, but MatrixId requires in way if there are multiple matrix in table. If there are just one matrix in table , throw MatrixId column out.